# Error with the message "Cannot cast (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211DimensionalTransmission*) to type 'const inet::physicallayer::IScalarSignal *'"

Tags: omnet++, inet

I use Omnet++ and Inet 4.4, I want to simulate a scenario to investigate the effect of interference, which is as follows:
In a network consisting of two pairs of nodes including a node called source and a node called destination, in which node source sends packets to node destination and is tuned in channel 2 of Ieee802.11b/g, let's examine the second pair consisting of node Node1 and node Node2, which node Node1 sends packets to node Node 4 and is tuned in channel 4.
But recently a problem appear very often and the simulations are stopped, the error is this:

```
check_and_cast(): Cannot cast (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211DimensionalTransmission*) to type 'const inet::physicallayer::IScalarSignal *' -- in module (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211Radio) AnalogModelShowcaseDistanceNetworkRM.source.wlan[1].radio (id=200), at t=0.001s, event #24
```

[image: Error message]
[image: Network schema]

My omnetpp.ini is as:

```
[Config Distance]
network = AnalogModelShowcaseDistanceNetworkRM

sim-time-limit = 5s

# Maryam **.radio.packetErrorRate.result-recording-modes = +vector
# Maryam **.radio.bitErrorRate.result-recording-modes = +vector

# application parameters
*.source.numApps = 1
*.source.app[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
*.source.app[*].destAddresses = "destination"
*.source.app[*].destPort = 1000
*.source.app[*].messageLength = 1000byte
*.source.app[*].sendInterval = 1ms

*.destination.numApps = 1
*.destination.app[0].typename = "UdpSink"
*.destination.app[*].localPort = 1000

*.Node1.numApps = 1
*.Node1.app[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
*.Node1.app[*].destAddresses = "Node2"
*.Node1.app[*].destPort = 1001
*.Node1.app[*].messageLength = 1000byte
*.Node1.app[*].sendInterval = 1ms

*.Node2.numApps = 1
*.Node2.app[0].typename = "UdpSink"
*.Node2.app[*].localPort = 1001

*.source.numWlanInterfaces = 2
*.destination.numWlanInterfaces = 2
*.Node1.numWlanInterfaces = 2
*.Node2.numWlanInterfaces = 2

*.source.wlan[*].radio.typename = "Ieee80211DimensionalRadio"
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.typename = "Ieee80211DimensionalRadio"
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.typename = "Ieee80211DimensionalRadio"
*.source.wlan[*].radio.centerFrequency = 2.412GHz
*.source.wlan[*].radio.bandwidth = 2MHz
*.source.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.power = 2mW
*.source.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.bitrate = 2Mbps
*.source.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.preambleDuration = 0s
*.source.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.headerLength = 96b
*.source.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.modulation = "BPSK"
*.source.wlan[*].radio.receiver.sensitivity = -85dBm
*.source.wlan[*].radio.receiver.energyDetection = -85dBm
*.source.wlan[*].radio.receiver.snirThreshold = 4dB
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.centerFrequency = 2.412GHz
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.bandwidth = 2MHz
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.power = 2mW
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.bitrate = 2Mbps
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.preambleDuration = 0s
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.headerLength = 96b
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.modulation = "BPSK"
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.receiver.sensitivity = -85dBm
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.receiver.energyDetection = -85dBm
*.destination.wlan[*].radio.receiver.snirThreshold = 4dB
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.centerFrequency = 2.412GHz
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.bandwidth = 2MHz
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.power = 2mW
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.bitrate = 2Mbps
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.preambleDuration = 0s
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.headerLength = 96b
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.modulation = "BPSK"
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.receiver.sensitivity = -85dBm
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.receiver.energyDetection = -85dBm
*.Node*.wlan[*].radio.receiver.snirThreshold = 4dB

*.source.wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 2
*.destination.wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 2
*.Node1.wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 4
*.Node2.wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 4

# mobility parameters
*.destination.mobility.typename = "LinearMobility"
*.destination.mobility.initialMovementHeading = 0deg
*.destination.mobility.speed = 200mps
*.destination.mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 500m
*.destination.mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 1200m

# wlan
*.source.**.transmitter.power = 12mW
*.source.**.displayCommunicationRange = true
**.backgroundNoise.power = -105dBm
**.wlan*.mac.*.rateSelection.dataFrameBitrate = 54Mbps
**.wlan*.mac.dcf.channelAccess.pendingQueue.packetCapacity = 14

# visualizer parameters
*.visualizer.*.numStatisticVisualizers = 2

*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[0].signalName = "packetSentToUpper"
*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[0].statisticExpression = "packetErrorRate"
*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[0].sourceFilter = "*.destination.wlan[*].radio"
*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[0].format = "packetErrorRate(Maryam): %v"

*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[1].signalName = "packetSentToUpper"
*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[1].statisticExpression = "minimumSnir"
*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[1].sourceFilter = "*.destination.wlan[*].radio"
*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[1].format = "SNIR(Maryam): %v"
*.visualizer.*.statisticVisualizer[1].placementHint = "topLeft"

*.visualizer.*.dataLinkVisualizer[0].displayLinks = true
*.visualizer.*.packetDropVisualizer[0].displayPacketDrops = true
*.visualizer.*.packetDropVisualizer[0].nodeFilter = "destination"
*.visualizer.*.packetDropVisualizer[0].labelFormat = "(Maryam) %r"
*.visualizer.*.infoVisualizer[0].displayInfos = true
*.visualizer.*.infoVisualizer[0].modules = "*.destination.app[0]"
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the radioMedium type to dimensional as well

```
radioMedium: Ieee80211DimensionalRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=62.247997,287.14398");
        }
```

In the NED file.